# Использование WebSokets

Tags: javascript, php, css, websocket, npm

**Про сам сайт**

Apache 2.4

Делаю сайт типа с новостной лентой, сообщениями и т.д. Но не хочу использовать XHR потому что считаю что это нагрузит всю сеть (у меня MySQL 8.0, за неё тоже боюсь)

Я использую на сайте **frontend** JavaScript + WebSoket + (CSS+HTML5 само собой)
А **backend** у меня node.js (npm) + JavaScript + WebSoket + PHP 7.1

---

**Вопросы такие:**

1. Нормально ли использовать всё это вместе
2. Нужно ли дополнительно шифровать сообщения при передаче через WS? Если да, то что лучше? Планирую сделать это AES-256
3. Что бы вы точно не стали делать на моем месте и куда лучше двигаться?

---

**P.S**
Программирую только неделю, так что прошу сильно не ругаться. Критику принимаю хорошо

Comment: 1) как по мне, не очень все вместе, хотя это только моё мнение  2) для безопасного общения по протоколу вебсокетов нужен домен с сертификатом (https) и вместо протокола ws используется wss... 3) как php может быть frontend ?))

Comment: @noname2019
1) ну просто так получается
2) Я знаю, но у меня сайт лежит на моем компьютере и в сеть выходит через OpenServer. А ssl пока покупать не хочу, потом сразу сделаю wss
3) Ну я имею ввиду что у меня страницы index.php

Comment: Избавиться от PHP на frontend, поскольку это невозможно :) Сначала провести тестирование и проверить, что наименее затратно по ресурсам - XHR или WebSocket в вашем случае. Только после этого выбирать технологию. Точно не стал бы заморачиваться с шифрованием, да и `SHA256` - это хеш функция.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Я очень извиняюсь, пока плохо знаю какие-то точные определения. Я хотел делать авторизацию\регистрацию на PHP но подумал что это будет не безопасно отправлять пароль на сервер чтобы зашифровать, как тогда это сделать? И да, перепутал с AES-256

Comment: У вас бакенд на node.js, зачем вы хотите авторизацию\регистрацию делать на PHP? Выберите что-то одно. По поводу шифрования пароля - это не нужно, используйте просто https.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Я не могу использовать https, у меня нет сертификата. А покупать его для проекта пока нет смысла.

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/ - есть бесплатные сертификаты

Comment: @Дмытрык У меня OpenServer, я все обыскал в их поиске, включая этот сервис